# Parsing multiple PHP code blocks among HTML

Tags: php, html

When inserting

```
<?php  ?>
```

Chunks into html it is easier for me to do ...

```
<?php  ?> some html <?php  ?> some html  <?php  ?> ect.
```

Is it better to do something like this...

```
<?php  echo "some html" ect. ?>
```

and if so how much is using the first method going to slow down my code?

Comment: PHP is meant to be parsed in a way like your second code block, so I would say you should be ok. Don't optimize before you need to so.

Comment: I swear I saw a question exactly like this maybe 4 days ago...

Comment: I swear I answered another @PhilipK question a couple days ago that never had a selected answer... `;)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP interpreter evaluates *only* the code between a pair of `<?php ?>` tags. While there *might* be a speed difference (I doubt it), even if one existed the difference would be completely undetectable.

I'd go with code readability.

Comment: I don't have a high-load environment, so Smarty templates, `HEREDOC`s, and double quoted strings usually do pretty well for me. It all has to do with the conditions on the server as it meets demand, with the possible exceptions of slow-moving db queries and mungled code and other externalities, none of which have to do with this question.